# LINQ and xml data

Tags: linq

I am learning LINQ and I am stuck on how to go about printing out the department name and the manager's name seperate.

The code I have below prints out:

```
Department name: Account
                Joe
Department name: Sales
                Jack
Department name: Pre-Sales
                Sam
Department name: Marketing
                Jim
```

How can I seperate it , so that it will only print the department name on that line.

```
string myXML = @"<Departments>
       <Department>Account
        <Manager>Joe</Manager>
        </Department>
       <Department>Sales
        <Manager>Jack</Manager>
        </Department>
       <Department>Pre-Sales
        <Manager>Sam</Manager>
        </Department>
       <Department>Marketing
        <Manager>Jim</Manager>
        </Department>
       </Departments>";

XDocument xdoc = new XDocument();
xdoc = XDocument.Parse(myXML);

var DeptResult = xdoc.Element("Departments").Descendants("Department");
var ManagerResult = xdoc.Element("Departments").Descendants("Manager");

foreach (XElement item in DeptResult)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Department Name - " + item.Value);
}
```

Comment: For each dept there is a manager?

Comment: Yes. thats correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `Zip` extension method:

```
var departments=xdoc.Descendants("Department");
var managers=xdoc.Descendants("Manager");
foreach( var s in departments.Zip(managers, (d,m)=>"Department name: "+ 
                                                    d.Value+"@\n"+
                                                   "Manager name: "+ m.Value ))
   Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Now, as far I remember Linq to XML returns the elements at the same order that are in your document and you said there is the same amount of departments and managers, so, you could also iterate for one of the results and use the index:

```
var departments=xdoc.Descendants("Department").ToList();
var managers=xdoc.Descendants("Manager").ToList();
for(int i=0;i<departments.Count;i++)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Department Name - " + departments[i].Value);
   Console.WriteLine("Manager Name - " + managers[i].Value);
}
```

Comment: This gives the error :  The name 'm' does not exist in the current context

Comment: I fixed that, now reading again your question, you want the manager name in a different line?

Comment: it prints like this: Department Name: Account   Joe Manager Name: Joe... and so on..  Need to get rid of the managers name from d.value..